# Logging module in python; is there a way to log everything less debug?

Tags: python, logging

Is there a way to log everything less debug?
I want write in a file the info, warning, critical and error, anything else.

This because logging the debug as well it become crazy to search something.

In this moment I'm doing:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='loggs.log', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info('Start Test API.')
```

In this way I record everything but I want limit it!

After read some documentation I'm doing this:

```
LEVELS = {'info': logging.INFO,
          'warning': logging.WARNING,
          'error': logging.ERROR,
          'critical': logging.CRITICAL}

#define the loggs configuration
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    level_name = sys.argv[1]
    level = LEVELS.get(level_name, logging.NOTSET)
    logging.basicConfig(filename='loggs.log', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',level=level)
logging.info('Start Test API.')
```

so I'm expecting that log 'Start Test API.', instead my file is empty!

Comment: Stack Overflow questions are meant to be one specific question. If your question was answered, you should accept the answer, and any new questions should be asked separately.

Comment: Hi @KevinMGranger, yes this is true but I just try the answer and it's not working for me so for me it's not a full correct answer to my question because it's not working

Comment: How did you call the program? Is its first parameter "info"? Put a `print("setting level", level)` in there and see what it says.

Comment: So the first parameter is info, this are the first lines of my code! when I try to print the level I receive "name 'level' is not defined" so I can see that it never enter in if len(sys.argv) > 1: but I don't know why :S

Comment: I opened a new file, wrote the same code and executed; the logs are printed on the screen but in the same case are not wrote in the file!

Comment: My example was to show you how the different levels worked, and that setting the level to INFO ignores DEBUG logs. Keep you original code, but on the second line at the end, change DEBUG to INFO.

Comment: I can't change it to info.... if I change to info errors and warning will not be logged, for this reason I posted here because I couldn't find a solution to log everything less DEBUG (and seeing that I'm not receiving an answer that solve my problem I don't neither understand the -2 of my question)

Comment: @Carlo1585 For sure you can stick your code to `info`. Makes no sense to claim that `info` will not log `errors` and `warnings` since the answer provided by @alxwrd demonstrates that when `info` is given as argument, all messages are printed except `debug` = what you requested.  Moreover , i did a test with your last code (sending the log to a file) and works fine for me.

Comment: I'm not sure why but it's not working for me :S; yes it print but they are not write in my log file :S

Comment: hey guys, can I ask you why I have a negative score on this question please? I'm trying to improve all my question but I don't really understand why I have a negative score on that one :S I understand that you told how to do and I accepted an answer even if the solution didn't work for me... I can even create a video if you want so you can see that doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='loggs.log', format='', datefmt='', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

You want:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='loggs.log', format='', datefmt='', level=logging.INFO)
```

See the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html

Example:

```
import logging
import sys

LEVELS = {'debug': logging.DEBUG,
          'info': logging.INFO,
          'warning': logging.WARNING,
          'error': logging.ERROR,
          'critical': logging.CRITICAL}

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    level_name = sys.argv[1]
    level = LEVELS.get(level_name, logging.NOTSET)
    logging.basicConfig(level=level)

logging.debug('This is a debug message')
logging.info('This is an info message')
logging.warning('This is a warning message')
logging.error('This is an error message')
logging.critical('This is a critical error message')
```

Produces:

```
$ python logging_level_example.py debug
DEBUG:root:This is a debug message
INFO:root:This is an info message
WARNING:root:This is a warning message
ERROR:root:This is an error message
CRITICAL:root:This is a critical error message

$ python logging_level_example.py info
INFO:root:This is an info message
WARNING:root:This is a warning message
ERROR:root:This is an error message
CRITICAL:root:This is a critical error message
```

Comment: It will log everything INFO and _above_. I have updated my answer with the example from the documentation.

Comment: Is there a reason you've linked to the 2.6 version of the documentation? Supported ended for it almost 4 years ago.

Comment: @KevinMGranger - It had a nice example. But good point, I will change the link, but keep the example.

Comment: I added what I'm doing in the answer because after change my code my log file is every time empty

Comment: Hi @alxwrd I just saw your update and it works fine :S thanks so much ;) ps just a curiosity, why do I have -3 on my question? any idea? I think that my question was good :(

Answer (score 0):

You can set the level to limit logging to by using the `setLevel` method.

Comment: could you please send me an example? if I set "Info" it will set just the info,  but I want log info, error, warning and critical